# problem with the 'Filling' command

Tags: filling

Hello colleagues!!

I have an issue with the `Filling` parameter in a `ListPlot`. I constructed an equilateral triangle of length 1, where I plot some points in barycentric coordinates, describing a curve and a line when joined. Here's a view:

[image: Figure 1]

For the model I'm describing, I need to fill with color the upper right region, inside the triangle, defined by a segment of the red line, a segment of the blue curve, and a segment of the right side of the triangle. The region seems like a right triangle, the hipotenuse being 'curve' (actually, the red line and the right side of the triangle are perpendicular).

I tried to use the Filling option of the `ListPlot` command, but I'm almost convinced that it's impossible to fill the described region using Filling. I'm currently working on another approach to put color in this region, but I think this could be a nice problem for anyone of you. Hats off for the one who can solve it, and thank you in advance!!

Daniel

PD:
Here's some code to replicate the exact figure:

```
k1 = Table[0.01 i, {i, 0, 100}];
yLine = k1 Sqrt[3]/2;
xLine = (Sqrt[3] k1 + yLine)/Sqrt[3];
k3 = Table[
  Solve[{x k1[[i]] == y 1/4, k1[[i]] + x + y == 1}, {x, y}], {i, 
   1, 101}][[All, 1]][[All, 1]][[All, 2]];
k4 = Table[
  Solve[{x k1[[i]] == y 1/4, k1[[i]] + x + y == 1}, {x, y}], {i, 
   1, 101}][[All, 1]][[All, 2]][[All, 2]];
yCurve = k3 Sqrt[3]/2;
xCurve = (Sqrt[3] k4 + yCurve)/Sqrt[3];
leftSide = Table[Sqrt[3] k1[[i]], {i, 1, 51}];
rightSide = Table[-Sqrt[3] (k1[[i]] - 1), {i, 51, 101}];
bottomSide = Table[0, {i, 1, 101}];
ListPlot[{Transpose[{k1, bottomSide}], 
  Transpose[{k1[[1 ;; 51]], leftSide}], 
  Transpose[{k1[[51 ;; 101]], rightSide}], Transpose[{xLine, yLine}], 
  Transpose[{xCurve, yCurve}]}, AspectRatio -> Sqrt[3]/2, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, Sqrt[3]/2}}, Joined -> True, 
  PlotStyle -> {Black, Black, Black, Red, Blue}]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: perhaps  `Filling -> {4 -> {{3}, {Blue, None}}, 4 -> {{5}, White}}`?

Answer (score 7):

```
lines = {{{0, 0}, {0, 1}}, {{0, 0}, {1/2, Sqrt[3]/2}}, 
         {{1/2, Sqrt[3]/2}, {1, 0}}, {{0, 0}, {1, 1/2}}};
curve = Join @@ ({y + x /2, Sqrt[3] x/2} /. 
     Table[Solve[{x k1[[i]] == y 1/4, k1[[i]] + x + y == 1}, {x, y}], {i, 1, 101}]);

ListLinePlot[{## & @@ lines, curve}, AspectRatio -> Sqrt[3]/2, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, Sqrt[3]/2}}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Black, Black, Black, Red, Blue},
 Filling -> {4 -> {{3}, {Yellow, None}}, 4 -> {{5}, White}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For non-white `Background`, change `White` to the background color:

```
ListLinePlot[{## & @@ lines, curve}, AspectRatio -> Sqrt[3]/2, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, Sqrt[3]/2}}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Black, Black, Black, Red, Blue}, Background -> Cyan,
 Filling -> {4 -> {{3}, {Yellow, None}}, 4 -> {{5}, Cyan}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: One might also choose to use `Transparent` instead of `White` for the fill if the background of the plot were not white.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis., `Transparent` instead of `White` does not cover the piece we need to cover. To deal with non-white `Background`, we need to use the background color in place of `White`.

Comment: Ah, after reading the docs for `Filling` I realized it now. Thanks for the correction!

Comment: Thanks kguler, you did it!! :-)

Comment: @cricricombowino, my pleasure. Welcome to mma.se.