# Colouring Regions of a Plot defined by more than equation

Tags: plotting, filling

How can I colour the two regions inside the triangle upper and down the parabola plotted together but with different intervals of the variables? The input text I wrote in *Mathematica* is

```
Show[
 Plot[{1/3 - 2/3 γ}, {γ, 0, 1/2}, AxesLabel -> {γ, λ}, PlotStyle -> CMYKColor[0, 0, 0, 1]],
 Plot[γ^2, {γ, 0, 1/3}, AxesLabel -> {γ, λ}, PlotStyle -> CMYKColor[0, 0, 0, 1]]]
```

Comment: For one of the regions, it's easy: `Plot[{1/3 - 2/3 γ, ConditionalExpression[γ^2, 0 <= γ <= 1/3]}, {γ, 0, 1/2}, AxesLabel -> {γ, λ}, Filling -> {2 -> {1}}, PlotStyle -> Black]`

Comment: Related/duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/83667/problem-with-the-filling-command

Answer (score 3):

```
Plot[{1/3 - 2/3 γ, Min[1/3 - 2/3 γ, γ^2]}, {γ, 0, 1/2}, 
    AxesLabel -> {γ, λ}, PlotStyle -> Black, 
    Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, Yellow}, 2 -> {Axis, Red}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer

Comment: @Michaels, my pleasure. Welcome to mma.se.